# how execute curl command in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, typescript

I have this command and need to execute my program in python

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST '192.168.1.149:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @file.json
```

Comment: How this is related to python 2.7 and python 3.x both?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: is this elasticsearch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

use [requests - HTTP for humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which allows you to send any HTTP query you like

```
import requests
r = requests.post('192.168.1.149:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty', json=datadict)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-ndjson',
}

params = (('pretty', ''),)

data = open('file.json', 'rb').read()
response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.149:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

**Note:** This is just a example according to your curl command.

Thankyou! Hope it helps you! :)